# How to call variables constructed in one class into another "parent" class

Tags: java, arrays, oop, inheritance, overriding

I am creating an OOP of a zoo. Here is my [UML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZKFp.png)

My zoo class contains a main while all of the other class do not. The monkey class extends the Animals class, in the Monkey class I want the monkeys to be created silently. Then in the Animals class, a method can override it so that I can 'theoretically' call  those monkeys in the Zoo class (as the zoo class contains the main).

```
public void monkeyEnclosure() {
        Monkey m1 = new Monkey ("Baby", "Monkey", "Baboon", "Brown", 8);
        monkeyAddition(m1);
        Monkey m2 = new Monkey ("Poppy", "Monkey", "Baboon", "Brown", 6);
        monkeyAddition(m2);
        Monkey m3 = new Monkey ("Dad", "Monkey", "Baboon", "Brown", 2);
        monkeyAddition(m3);
        Monkey m4 = new Monkey ("Mom", "Monkey", "Baboon", "White", 9);
        monkeyAddition(m4);
        Monkey m5 = new Monkey ("Sister", "Monkey", "Baboon", "Black", 7);
        monkeyAddition(m5);
    }
```

(These monkeys are placed in a Monkey array to be  displayed all of the information. I want the array to be able to be called from the Zoo class, but the array always comes up null.)

I am super fresh to object oriented programming, I don't even know how to properly explain what I am having trouble with. But my main question is how can I call these class constructors from a separate class, and display that information in the 'parent' class.

I've been tinkering with the code for over 3 hours and have not come to any conclusion as to how to fix the issue. If you need any access to my code or any further clarification, I am free to send, just let me know!

Answer (score 1):

A class called Monkey should have information about a single monkey. An animal class that monkey and lion have as a superclass should have information that is common to any animal (like name or age or country of origin). It's not the place to cram in other stuff like methods that create a bunch of monkeys. Objects need to be focused on representing one thing.

It sounds like you're missing the concept of an exhibit which is populated by a number of animals. This should be a separate object, not a method tacked onto something else.  The zoo can contain multiple exhibits each of which can have a populate method that takes care of creating animals. This way the animal subclasses each track info about individual animals, and the exhibit acts as a container for multiple animals, so each object has a single responsibility.